# how to scroll an array of text?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dynamic-arrays, text-widget

I am currently working on a web site for a boy scout troop and I have a database of young men that have earned there eagle scout. I was wanting that data to scroll across a text widget in WordPress. I currently have the plugins to make it work I'm just struggling with the code side of it. I have some php code to send the database to my array. My current issue is getting a dynamic array from my php to my js function and then making it scroll from right to left. what would be the best way to go about this?

.php

```
$Eagle = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $Eagle[] = "#".$row[numb]."     ".$row['FName']." ".$row['LName']."      ".$row['Date'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your `$Eagle` array to a string using `implode()` ([php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) and put it into an `<marquee>` element

```
echo '<marquee behaviour="scroll">' . implode(' | ', $Eagle) . '</marquee>';
```

for more options, have a look [here](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

*EDIT*

an alternative way of doing what you're trying to accomplisch:

```
echo '<marquee behaviour="scroll">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  echo "#{$row[$numb]}    {$row['FName']} {$row['LName']}     {$row['Date']}";
echo '</marquee>';
```

Comment: i want to get the Scroll off the server side to reduce the Data travel to and from the server.

Comment: there's not gonna be any server side load because of the marquee. with `echo` you send the response to the client (browser) which will simply get the text `<marquee behaviour.... /marquee>` and THEN the BROWSER will render it to be a proper scrolling text. maybe you should read some introductions on php and html. thats basic stuff.